# Rails restful resources instead of GET URL path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

How can I reform this code using resources and restful agreement?

```
  def render_with_hashtags_of_question(text)
    text.gsub(TAG_REGEX){
      |word| link_to word, "/questions/hashtag/#{word.mb_chars.downcase.delete('#')}"
    }.html_safe
  end
```

routes:

```
get '/questions/hashtag/:name', to: 'questions#hashtags'
```

Thanks a lot in advance, guys!

Comment: It's slightly unclear what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, I've tried to get something like `resources :questions do :hashtag, only: [:index] end` in routes, and according changes in `render_with_hashtags_of_question(text)` method :) So what should I do for making these amends? :)

Comment: Is `questions` a real resource or just a namespace?

Comment: yep, real resource, full code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513009/rails-url-paths-and-resource-routing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. Thanks everyone who tried to help! :) The answer is here: [Rails url paths and resource routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513009/rails-url-paths-and-resource-routing)